# how to use only last few layers of vgg16 using pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

To train the whole network OF VGG16 is very lengthy and it takes a lot of time. 
i don't know how to select only last few layers of vgg 16 as my network is taking more than 6 hours only for 2 epochs and i want to pre-train my vgg16 model over the last few layers only. is this possible ? if so, then how?

Comment: I am unsure if I understand. What do you mean by "pre-train over the last few layers"? Don't you mean that you want to have a pretrained vgg16 and **re**-train the last few layers only? Or would you like to have a vgg-like model which is just shallower (only has the last few layers)?

Comment: yes exactly you got it. i have loaded a pre train vgg16 but i just want to train the last few layers. how can i do that?